# How to add multiple score results PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, scoring

I want to add multiple scores, but if I do it this way the second fill in form isn't working. The first fill in form is working well. I know this is not a nice code how can I do this with one code type?

Hope you can help.

This is my code:

```
<form action="e2admin.php" method="post">
            <div class="input-group">
             <input style="width:410px;" type="text" class="form-control" name="date" placeholder="Datum" /><br>
                <select name="thuisteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control" name="scorethuis1" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control" name="scoreuit1" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam1">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <select name="thuisteam2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>

                </select>
                <input style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control" name="scorethuis2" placeholder="0" />
                -
                <input style="width:20px; text-align:center;" type="text" class="form-control" name="scorethuis2" placeholder="0" />
                <select name="uitteam2">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <?php
                        mysql_data_seek($result, 0);

                        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                               echo '<option value="' . $row['Team'] . '">' . $row['Team'] . '</option>';
                            }
                        }
                     ?>
                </select><br>
                <input style="margin-left:330px;" type="submit" class="form-control" value="Toevoegen" />
                </div>
            </form>         
                    <?php

                    if( $_POST['scorethuis1'] > $_POST['scoreuit1']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+3 WHERE Team ='".$_POST['thuisteam1']."'");

                    }
                    else if( $_POST['scorethuis1'] > $_POST['scoreuit1']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+3 WHERE Team ='".$_POST['uitteam1']."'");

                    }
                    else if( $_POST['scorethuis1'] == $_POST['scoreuit1']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+1 WHERE Team in ('".$_POST['thuisteam1']."', '".$_POST['uitteam1']."') ");

                    }

                    else if( $_POST['scorethuis2'] > $_POST['scoreuit2']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+3 WHERE Team ='".$_POST['thuisteam2']."'");

                    }
                    else if( $_POST['scorethuis2'] > $_POST['scoreuit2']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+3 WHERE Team ='".$_POST['uitteam2']."'");

                    }
                    else if( $_POST['scorethuis2'] == $_POST['scoreuit2']) {
                            //echo $_POST["thuisteam1"]; 
                            mysql_query("UPDATE e2teams SET Punten = Punten+1 WHERE Team in ('".$_POST['thuisteam2']."', '".$_POST['uitteam2']."') ");

                    }

                    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats some weird logic you have going on there, what you're basically saying is:

```
$foo = 1
if($foo > 1) {//you'll skip this}
else if($foo > 1) {//and this}
else if($foo == 1) {//and get here}

$foo = 2
if($foo > 1) {//you'll get here}
else if($foo > 1) {//skip this}
else if($foo == 1) {//and this}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve but I would consider revising